# por la ciudad, по городу, across(?)/over(?) the city

Tags: word-choice

(The title is in Spanish and Russian, because I'm not sure what's the best way to say it in English either.)

I'd like to say that I took a walk **in the city** (and visited many different places on the way), or that I drove **across the country** (from place to place, visiting many places). What would be the right prepositions and/or adverbs to use for it in German? Something with `über`? Maybe something with `quer`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is "durch"

> Ich fahre/laufe/reise durch die Stadt, das Land, den Park.

"Durch" can also mean the more simple traversing so if you really want to put emphasis on the "here and there and there", the criss cross trajectory, then you'd use "in" + "umher"

> Ich laufe/fahre/reise in dem Land, in der Stadt, in dem Park umher.

However, this has a slight touch of having lost your path. It sounds a little aimless in the negative way and it does not imply "tourist" as much as "durch" does.

Answer (score 2):

`kreuz und quer` can be used.

> Ich bin kreuz und quer durch Europa gefahren und habe 15 Länder gesehen.

This has a slight connotation of zig-zagging, though.

Another possibility is `durch den/die/das ganze(n) Ort/Stadt/Land`.

> Ich bin gestern durch die ganze Stadt gelaufen um ein paar rote Schuhe zu finden.

The English equivalent would be `all over`.

> I've searched all over the park but I could not see a single red flower.